Display search results within same page using elementor as page builder
I have been using elementor for page builder tried to show the results in same page but once form submitted navigated to next page. Is there a way to add any php code in this elementor section.

You'll have to check with Elementor, that's third party code and has it's own behaviors and nuance.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
